# Multiple ingress rules in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I have a default namespace with nginx, some apps and one ingress rule.
I want to create a test environment in the same cluster, different namespace: test.
I duplicated everything except nginx controller (this is in default namespace).

Unfortunatelly, the Ingress rule file (the one with kind:ingress) from test is ignored by the nginx from default namespace.
Is there a rule that "2 different rules of the same ingress must be in the same namespace"?
Should I use an nginx controller for every namespace?

The rules are the same , just the "path" is prefixed with "test".

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: my-ingress
namespace: test
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
selfLink: /apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/test/ingresses/my-ingress
status:
loadBalancer: {}
spec:
rules:
- http:
    paths:
      - path: /testapp1/
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: what do you mean by different rules ? one ingress should be fair enough. What is inside each ingress ? can you please add it here ?

Comment: why would u need different ingress controllers ? But it makes sense to use different ingress file or different namespace